# Get command of a hashmap with a parameter different than the key in the hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a custom class as my key in my hashmap like so

```
// In the main function
HashMap<Drink, boolean> drinkMap = new HashMap<>();

// What I would like to be able to do:
drinkMap.get("beer");

// My drink Class which is used as the key
public class Drink implements Comparable<String> {
    private String name;
    private String info;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public Drink(String name, String info) {
        this.name = name;
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have the get method for the hashmap compare the string that is passed in to Drink.name and if they are the same then return that hashmap entry, but I cannot figure out how to get this to work.

I tried implementing the equals and hashcode methods in my Drink class like so:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Name.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof String && o.equals(Name);
}
```

But when I would do hashMap.get("beer") it kept returning null even though I know there exists a Drink object with the name "beer" in the map.

Comment: Why don't you use the name as the key?

Comment: If you took 2 mins to look at the source of `HashMap` you will see why this will never work. If that is not clear a step debugger will make it painfully clear.

Comment: To be completely honest with you there isn't a reason why I couldn't. I could refactor it so that the boolean value is a part of the Drink class or end up using two maps. But I thought that if this could work it might end up being more simple... starting to realize that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea.  You should always query a map with the same type (or a subtype thereof) as the intended key.  Not doing that only opens you up to problems (as I'm sure you've started to notice).

You should consider either making the key of your map a `String` type, or querying your map by `Drink`.

(As to why your specific case isn't working: `"beer".equals(drink) != drink.equals("beer")`.)

Comment: The last part is the real terrible part IMO.